# graphviz multiples edges on the same node

Tags: graphviz

I'm new on graphviz and need to create a graph for a netstat output like this image

[image: Netstat Connection]

but I can't add more than one connection to the same node, the grapviz overwrite and display only the last connection.

Comment: Welcome, please show what you tries sofar and where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a good start with the following (I didn't want to type all the numbers):

```
digraph g {

rankdir=LR

node [shape=box ]
x1[label="10.112.11.115"]

x1 -> x2[label="64939:0"]
x1 -> x2[label=1]
x1 -> x3[label=0]
x1 -> x4[label=1]
x1 -> x5[label=0]
x1 -> x5[label=1]

}
```